# File IO in Java task

Tags: java, file-io

It is called Marks Processing and basically my task is to write a program that reads in the information from three files and output a listing of the results for each student, ordered in descending order of overall mark.

I have saved the 3 Files and the first file contains student name and id, the next two files contains the coursework and exam marks. The output for each student should comprise two lines:
Line 1: Student id followed by student name
Line 2: Coursework, exam and aggregate marks for each module followed by overall mark

Marks should show one digit after the decimal point.

In the listing, the results for each student should be separated by a row of “-“.  I had some code to make this work but the file cannot be found eventhough the files are all saved on my desktop.

The code I have is here:

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student implements Comparable {
    String name;
    int id;
    double ab101mark;
    double ab102mark;
    double aggregate;

    public Student(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        return (int)(((Student)obj).aggregate - this.aggregate);
    }

    public void setAggregate() {
        aggregate = (ab101mark + ab102mark)/2;
    }

    public void printTranscript(PrintWriter destination) {
        destination.println(id + "\t " + name);
        destination.printf("AB101\t %4.1f\t AB102\t %4.1f\t Aggregate   %4.1f\n", ab101mark, ab102mark, aggregate);
        destination.println("----------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
public class MarksProcessor {

    private static Student findStudent(int idnum, ArrayList<Student> clist) {
        for (Student s : clist) {
            if (s.id == idnum) return s;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Student> classList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        File inFile = new File("C:/Users/mobin/Desktop/ABStudents.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int id = input.nextInt();
            String name = input.next();
            Student s = new Student(name, id);
            classList.add(s);

        }
        input.close();

        inFile = new File("C:/Users/mobin/Desktop/AB101.txt");
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int id = input.nextInt();
            double mark = input.nextDouble();
            Student s = findStudent(id, classList);
            s.ab101mark = mark;

        }

        input.close();

        inFile = new File("C:/Users/mobin/Desktop/AB102.txt");
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            int id = input.nextInt();
            double mark = input.nextDouble();
            Student s = findStudent(id, classList);
            s.ab102mark = mark;

        }
        input.close();
        for (Student s : classList) {
            s.setAggregate();
        }

        File outFile = new File("ABRankedList.txt");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        for (Student s : classList) s.printTranscript(output);
        output.close();
    }

}
```

In the listing, the results for each student should be separated by a row of “-“.
The output should look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
```

14321 Elizabeth

AB101: 80.2 70.4 73.3 AB102: 75.2 70.4 72.3 Overall mark: 72.8

---

14654 Charlie

AB101: 85.4 60.2 67.8 AB102: 80.4 65.2 71.3 Overall mark: 69.5

Comment: Please share your code and the exact error so it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I shall update the question :).

Comment: @Mureinik is there anyway I can directly chat to you about this please?

Comment: Where are your files located and how do you run this code?

Comment: "*is there anyway I can directly chat to you about this please?*" there is a chat on SO, but if you have new informations related to this question you should post it here so all users (future readers and potential answerers) could see them.

Comment: You  can also add `System.out.println(outFile.getAbsolutePath())` to find out where Java is looking for the files

Comment: Rather than telling us the whole assignment you are trying to solve, write the minimum amount of code whose behavior is not what you expect, and make that into a concise question. If you're getting a FileNotFoundException, you should only need a few lines to demonstrate it and the answer will be easy for someone to write. You may even find that it's easier for you to figure out yourself if the number of moving pieces is reduced. That is what we all do when stuff doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is the files are saved on the desktop and the code is running in a different directory so the files aren't in your code's classpath. That's why Java can't find them.

If you change the pathname you pass to new File() to be the absolute path of the file, I believe it will work.

Comment: ahh I am still confused :O. Do I still the original infile I had?

Comment: It will be changed to something like File inFile = new File("C:\Users\yourUserName\Desktop\ABStudents.txt"); for the first file.

Comment: oh ok, so I do that for the three files I suppose? Do I not have to create a separate project for just the Students where I do the aggregate marks and all?

Comment: Yes, that will be needed for each of the files.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a separate project, but you will have to make additional methods / possibly classes to store the data and then manipulate it to get the results you need.

Comment: I did that, I am getting an output but it is not what it should be :(.

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to update your code and the update you are seeing. Have you tried debugging and seeing if it is doing what you are expecting?

Comment: I have updated it but I have an error now. Let me update the question and show the current code I have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path when opening the file:

```
File inFile = new File("ABStudents.txt");
```

Should be something like:

```
File inFile = new File("C:/Users/myUserID/Desktop/ABStudents.txt");
```

There are ways to get the users home directory from system properties if it needs to be more flexible.

Comment: I ran it. I shall put my output in the question.